# windows authentication: negotiate, ntlm and kerberos

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

First of all are `negotiate`, `ntlm` and `kerberos` three different implementation of windows authentication?

IE sends this:
`Authorization: Negotiate YIIFswYGKwYB ...`

Firefox sends this:
`Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAA ...`

Do they use different protocols? If so how to configure iis 7.0 so that only `ntlm` would be used?

p.s. iis is configured to use windows auth, but both browsers throw login forms and login only succeeds for firefox.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, no.

Practically, yes.

Technically Kerberos is the technological successor to NTLM. But you can use either to authenticate against a Windows domain/server. If you select negotiate, your browser will attempt to authenticate in whatever way is successful, which is sometimes NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up...

Safari on iOS (from 7 to 7.0.2, and then 8 as well, it seems) [has troubles with Kerberos](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5327078?start=0&tstart=0), so if you have to support iPhones/iPads, disable Negotiate and only have NTLM.